# Conexión a base de datos Access con C#

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

Tengo un problema de sintaxis, creo que el caracter `\` no me deja conectar con Access.
**¿Qué puede estar pasando?**

```
class dataclass
{
    public string conec = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C: \ Users\heribertol\Desktop\Pocket\Pocket.accdb;";
    OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection();

    public void open()
    {
        cn.Open();
    }
    public void close()
    {
        cn.Close();
    }
    public DataTable tabla()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("select * FROM Sheet1 ", cn);

        da.Fill(ds);

        dt = ds.Tables[0];

        return dt;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El carácter `\` es el [*caracter de escape*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/aa691087(v=vs.71).aspx) en c y la mayoría de los lenguajes que tienen sintaxis basadas en c, incluido c#.

Esto te permite incluir caracteres especiales, como el retorno de línea, etc. utilizando cadenas *normales*.

En resumen, para introducir un caracter `\`, debes utilizar la *secuencia de escape* `\\`. Así, tu cadena quedaría algo así:

```
public string conec = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\heribertol\\Desktop\\Pocket\\Pocket.accdb;"
```

Para generalizar un poco el tema, además del caracter `\`, valiéndote de las secuencias de escape, puedes introducir otros caracteres en una cadena, tales como:

```
\0     Null 
\b     Retroceso    
\f     Avance de página 
\n     Nueva línea
\r     Retorno de carro
\t     Tabulador horizontal
```

En [la documentación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/aa691087(v=vs.71).aspx) encontrarás un listado completo de las secuencias de escape existentes en c#.

Answer (score 0):

Tambien lo puedes corregir agregando un arroba "@" al inicio de tu string de la cadena de conexion asi:

```
@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\heribertol\Desktop\Pocket\Pocket.accdb;";
```